# Windows Mail app storage

Tags: email, windows-10, windows-mail

I'm using Microsoft Outlook for my email but I've found out that the Windows Mail (metro app) was also downloading emails. 
I found this out because I was running out of diskspace. There is about 20GB of data stored in

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Packages\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_<id>\LocalState\LiveComm\<id>\<id>\Att
```

I disabled downloading emails, but now the data is still there. Can I just delete the content of that LiveComm directory or is there another way of clearning up that space from the Mail app (without losing my emails from Microsoft Outlook)?

Comment: Outlook and Windows Mail are two independent programs.  Outlook does not even store its data files in that directory nor does it have that capability to do so.

Comment: ok and can I just delete that entire directory?

Comment: That is entirely up to you.  The folder and files contained in that folder are not used by Outlook.